# Creating a canonical with PHP

Tags: php, html, xhtml, seo

I need PHP code to generate a dynamic canonical URL within the `<link />` tag as follows:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="php goes here" />
```

My site uses PHP to generate variables as follows:

```
http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var1=blue&var2=large&pointlessvar=narrow
```

I want to be able to return a canonical URL that removes the `&pointlessvar=narrow`

And re-arranges the variables in the manner as I see fit, like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var2=large&var1=blue" />
```

I want to do this for SEO purposes as my site contains many variables in different orders that give different URL'S for essentially the same content (to prevent duplication in the SERPS and to concentrate the link juice)

Can anybody suggest some PHP code that I can place in the `<link />` tag?

Comment: According to what criteria does `&pointlessvar=narrow` treated as useless?

Comment: you should start by using url-rewriting / seo-friendly url. It'll be worth to do that and it'll avoid you to have to such canonical.

Comment: @zerkms perhaps the calling it pointlessvar was slightly misleading - my bad. It isn't completely useless - it allows my visitors to narrow their search results but it may cause duplicate content which I don't want the search engines to index and hence I need to generate a canonical URL to remove it from the SERPS.

Comment: @Boris Guéry - I don't want to start re-writing the actual URL's as my site is live and has thousands of indexed pages in the SERPS. Re-writing the URLS' sounds like a re-direction nightmare :)

Comment: @Matt: I still can't get the criteria of selection, which variables should present in "canonical URL" and which shouldn't.

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: @zerkms - Basically, I choose the selection criteria. If you can give an example of code that takes `http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var1=blue&var2=large&pointlessvar=narrow` and returns `http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var2=large&var1=blue` that would be appreciated :) I can then re-arrange the code as needed.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I use PHP version 5.2.9

Comment: `function do_the_magic($url) { if ($url == 'http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var1=blue&var2=large&pointlessvar=narrow') return 'http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var2=large&var1=blue'; }` Try rearrange this?

Comment: @zerkms - If only it was as easy as an if - then function lol. Code needs to be dynamic according to the displayed URL. Basically I need to re-build the URL. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt: but it does what you need. You did not describe how and according to what to rebuild the url. `dynamic` is not enough detailed explanation of your task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a canonical url, you should actually make sure, you got only the parameters you need and put them in a fixed order too. This code does that. It filters the list of _GET paramters and build a new url with only the desired ones. I put it some comments, so you can easily adjust this code to fit your needs.

I use array_filter, because I'm not sure what happens if you unset array elements within a foreach on the array.

```
function params()
{
    return array('b', 'c', 'a', 'z');
}

function checkParam($a)
{
    // Checks if key $a is in array of valid parameters
    return in_array($a, params());
}

function compare($a, $b)
{
    return array_search($a, params()) - array_search($b, params());
}

function getCanonicalUrl()
{
    $querystring = '';

    // Copy and flip the array to allow filtering by key.
    $params = array_flip($_GET);

    // Filter out any params that are not wanted.
    $params = array_filter($params, 'checkParam'); 

    // If none remain, we're done.
    if (count($params) !== 0)
    {
        // Sort the rest in given order
        uasort($params, 'compare');
        // Create a query string. Mind, name and value are still flipped.
        $querystring = '?'.http_build_query(array_flip($params));
    }

    return 
        'http://'.
        // $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
        $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] .
        $querystring;
}

print getCanonicalUrl();
```

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, This is great! Thanks for your help - it almost does everything I need apart from 2 issues. 1) The code seems to produce a URL that duplicates the domain name and is missing the http:// prefix, for example it returns the following URL: `www.mysite.com/www.mysite.com/script.php?var2=large&var1=blue` 2) how can I arrange the variables in the returned URL so that they are in the exact order that I specify in  `funtion checkParam($a)` ? Thanks again for your time - were nearly there!!

Comment: It shouldn't do that, but maybe the domain is already included in the SCRIPT_NAME. If so, just skip HTTP_HOST. You will need to add 'http://' yourself. The actual protocol prefix cannot be found in $_SERVER. And if you skip the line with `asort`, your variables will not be sorted.

Comment: Hi GolezTrol, thanks for your response. Adding the http:// prefix sorted the problem perfectly :). I still have a problem with the order in which the variables are sorted, removing `asort` did not help, the variables just appear in a random order now. I wanted them to be in the exact order I specify in `funtion checkParam($a)` Sorry to be such a pain!

Comment: Just to clarify, having removed `asort` the variables are now being returned in the order that they appear in the actual URL, not in the order that they are listed in `funtion checkParam($a)`

Comment: I made another modification. Added the `compare()` function that compares two keys by their index in the array of params. Instead of `asort` I now use `uasort` that accepts a callback in the same way as array_filter. It allows you to specify a custom compare function. I also moved the array to a separate function, so you don't have to declare it twice. It could also be a global, although you're coming to the point where you could also put all in a specific class. (But that's another chapter. :) )

Comment: GolezTrol you are a legend, this works perfectly! Please accept the best answer as a thank you :)

Comment: Hi again GolezTrol, I have posted a follow up question to this one as I have encountered an unexpected problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838847/php-to-compare-and-return-a-variable-in-a-querystring I need to add a snippet of code to one of the specified variables in `function params()` to compare and return the correct variable. Be grateful if you could take a peek :) thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
$path = "http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var1=blue&var2=large&pointlessvar=narrow";
$url = parse_url($path, PHP_URL_QUERY); // Fetch the query component of a url

// Put the query into an array with the var name as the key
parse_str($url, $query=array()); 

foreach ($query as $name=>$val) {
    // Check for pointless vars and unset() them here
}

krsort ($query); // Sort by array keys in reverse order.

$pathex = explode('?', $path, 2);
$npath = $pathex[0] . '?' . http_build_query($query);
```

There are more sort function available by php.
They even allow you to write your own [custom sort function](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php).

Comment: Didn't know about the PHP_URL_QUERY constant parameter, thanks

Comment: @Boris Guéry yea i didn't know about it until i saw someone else on here use it haha

Answer (score 1):

You can mix [`parse_url();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function and [`http_build_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to rebuild your url.

```
$url = 'http://www.mysite.com/script.php?var1=blue&var2=large&pointlessvar=narrow';
$url = parse_url($url);

$params = array();
$tmpParams = explode('&',$url['query']);

foreach ($tmpParams as $param) {
    $tmp = explode('=', $param);
    $params[$tmp[0]] = (!empty($tmp[1])) ? $tmp[1] : null;
}
```

Then loop through $params to unset useless variables and then rebuild with http_build_query.

Comment: `http_build_query()` can lose data in some cases.

Comment: @zerkms, can you point any source about this? I've never had problems before.

Comment: oops, missed with `parse_str()` and its dot-issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $_SERVER superglobal and the $_GET superglobal to get the various parts of the url. You can rearrange and filter them anyway you like.