# PHP to compare and return a variable in a querystring

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I need a bit of simple PHP code that can return a specified variable if any one of three variables is contained within a query string. Probably easier to explain like this:

`if {querystring} contains {var1} or {var2} or {var3} return {var1}`

This is expands on the following question: [Creating a canonical with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837830/creating-a-canonical-with-php)

I need to add said code to one of the variables specified in `function params`, in the linked question.

Comment: The answer you got to the linked question (parse_url()+parse_str()) + in_array() + a bit of thinking. Shouldn't be too hard to do something yourself.

Comment: @svens - Unfortunately I didn't learn PHP. Maybe now is a good time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to analyse the query string of the current request:

```
array_search($var1,$_GET)!==false OR array_search($var2,$_GET)!==false ....
```

else:

```
$vars = array();
parse_string($queryString,$vars);
if(array_search($var1,$vars)!==false OR array_search($var2,$vars)!==false ...
```

.

Answer (score 1):

```
function evaluateThis($var1,$var2,$var3) {
   if((strpos($string,$var1) !== false) || (strpos($string,$var1) !== false) || (strpos($string,$var1) !== false)) {
       return $var1;
   }
   else { return 'string not found'; }
 }
```

Is this what you mean

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for the answer. The code looks simple enough, I have added it into the `function params` as in my previous question but I cant seem to get it to work :) Here's how I've added in - perhaps there's a problem with my syntax? function params()
{return array('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5', 'if((strpos($string,$var1) !== false) || (strpos($string,$var2) !== false) || (strpos($string,$var3) !== false)) {return $var1;');
}

Comment: you were returning an array of strings, none of the calculations were being completed within quotes '

Comment: try this.. i re-wrote your code, try to figure out what and why, but feel free to ask me :)  function params() {
  $vars = array('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4', 'var5');
  $search=array_search('var1',$vars);
  $vars[]=$search;
  return $vars;
 }
 print_r(params());

Comment: Thanks for your time spent on this Mike. I couldn't get your code to work in the way that I wanted, but perhaps that is because I should improve my understanding of PHP. So that is what I will do. Cheers.